# After ImportJson Path is not editable in paper.js

Tags: javascript, paperjs

Here is the below code for export and import of paper js layouts.

```js
$('#btnSave').click(function () {
     var json = paper.project.activeLayer.exportJSON();
     localStorage.setItem('oncjson', json);
     alert('Data has been save successfully;');
});

$('#btnGet').click(function () {
     var json = localStorage.getItem('oncjson');
     paper.project.activeLayer.importJSON(json);
     paper.project.view.update();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.11.5/paper-full.js"></script>
```

It is loading data as per expectations but once the import has done, I am not able to alter or drag segments from the path. it is like hardcode design rendered on the canvas.

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: You are not manipulating the path segments in any way in your posted code. PaperJS doesn't allow you to to interact with the path using your mouse without writing any code to do so.

Answer (score 1):

From what you are describing, I think the problem is that you are expecting that event handlers will be imported along with the serialized data.
Unfortunately, that is not the case because custom callbacks are hardly serializable (see this [issue](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/1497) for more details).

Here is an example simulating export/import in 2 separated canvas.
You can see that, after importing, we need to attach event handlers manually.

```js
// create one scope per canvas
var scope1 = new paper.PaperScope();
scope1.setup(document.getElementById('canvas1'));
var scope2 = new paper.PaperScope();
scope2.setup(document.getElementById('canvas2'));

// draw a circle in canvas 1
new paper.Path.Circle({
  center: scope1.view.center,
  radius: 50,
  fillColor: 'orange',
  parent: scope1.project.activeLayer,
  // name it so we can easily find it in hierarchy
  name: 'circle'
});

// draw instructions
new paper.PointText({
  content: 'Drag the circle around',
  justification: 'center',
  point: scope1.view.center.subtract(0, 80),
  parent: scope1.project.activeLayer
});

// bind custom drag handler to circle (using its name to find it)
scope1.project.activeLayer.children['circle'].onMouseDrag = customDragHandler;

// export canvas 1 content
var json = scope1.project.exportJSON();

// import it into canvas 2
scope2.project.importJSON(json);

// we need to manually attach event handler for canvas 2 as it wasn't serialized
scope2.project.activeLayer.children['circle'].onMouseDrag = customDragHandler;

// this position the item under the mouse pointer when it is dragged
function customDragHandler(event) {
  this.position = event.point;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

canvas {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.11.5/paper-core.min.js"></script>

<main>
  <canvas id="canvas1" resize></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas2" resize></canvas>
</main>
```